# How is it possible to replace a relay with transistors?

Tags: transistors, relay, polarity

As we all know:

- A relay's COM and NO pins have no polarity, they will work fine when polarity is reversed.
- A transistor's Collector and Emitter pins have polarity and this polarity must be respected.

So:

1. how can you replace a 4 pin Normally Open (SPST) relays with transistors when polarity of Emitter and Collector pins are unknown?
2. Are there any specific components out there that can switch a DC voltage when polarity is unknown?

(I'm a software guy and a noob in hardware world, so, if it is possible, please explain or add an image for better understanding)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *how can you replace a 4 pin Normally Open (SPST) relays with
> transistors when polarity of Emitter and Collector pins are unknown?*

Well, I wouldn't use BJTs; I'd use MOSFETs and, two back-to-back MOSFETs with a common photovoltaic drive interface is commonly used in "solid state relays" aka SSRs. Here's a typical example: -

[image]

And here's a photovoltaic interface chip that can be used with external MOSFETs: -

[image]

And, the great thing about this type of circuit is that you have isolation between input and output (just like a relay) and, it can operate on AC and DC.

> *Are there any specific components out there that can switch a DC
> voltage when polarity is unknown?*

The above SSR circuits work just fine but you have to be aware of certain things. The switching is faster than a relay but usually only in the realm of 1 ms. This is mainly due to the photovoltaic part and the need to charge up the gate-source capacitors in any MOSFET.

You should also be aware that switching an inductive load can lead to a recoil voltage (aka a back-emf) and quite often you'll need extra protection circuits to prevent the MOSFETs seeing too-high a voltage when they turn off.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use BJTs (TIP122/TIP127 for heavy load or 2n2222/2N2907 for light loads)? I already have a lot of them in hands and as I need to replace a lot of relays in my design, the cost of buying new power MOSFETs could go higher than expected for a prototype of a hobby project.

Comment: Not really because they don’t naturally have reverse protection diodes and their reverse characteristic is quite different to their forward characteristic (unlike MOSFETs). BJTs also need a base current making them fairly unsuitable for being optically driven via a photovoltaic interface. MOSFETs rule in this type of application I’m sorry to say.

Comment: So I guess It's better to stick to cheaper mechanical relays as SSRs or diy SSRs (like designs that you posted) are several times more expensive in my country. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @jozyah.etienne OK if you're done with this now maybe you should [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand the motivation behind people giving free help on this site.

Comment: Yeah sorry I forgot that.